# Building Dynamic JSON Dict with PHP and cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I was wondering how I could merge the variables at the top of my PHP file with the dict in my cURL POST method.

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "CUSTOM_URL",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"email_address\": \"thisperson@gmail.com\", \"status\": \"subscribed\", \"merge_fields\": {\"FNAME\": \"Bob\", \"LNAME\": \"Dylan\"}}",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Basic UN:PW",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
      ),
    ));
```

So essentially, how do I put First Name, Last Name, Email, etc into `"{\"email_address\": \"thisperson@gmail.com\", \"status\": \"subscribed\", \"merge_fields\": {\"FNAME\": \"Bob\", \"LNAME\": \"Dylan\"}}"` (to replace `thisperson@gmail.com`, `Bob`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$data = [
    'email_address' => $_POST['email'],
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields' => [
        'FNAME' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'LNAME' => $_POST['last_name'],
    ],
];

...
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `json_encode` to just create a whole new json string with the variables you need. The alternative would be trying to string replace on the json string.

```
 $fields = json_encode([
  'FNAME' => $_POST['first_name'], 
  'LNAME' => $_POST['last_name'], 
  'email_address' => $_POST['email'], 
  'status' => 'subscribed'
]);
```

Then in your output:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that use `http_build_query` function. try this:

```
$postfields = [
    'email_address' => $_POST['email'],
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields' => [
        'FNAME' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'LNAME' => $_POST['last_name']
    ]
]

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "CUSTOM_URL",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query( $postfields ),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "authorization: Basic UN:PW",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: plain/text",
    ],
));
```

Or with JSON:

```
$postfields = [
    'email_address' => $_POST['email'],
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields' => [
        'FNAME' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'LNAME' => $_POST['last_name']
    ]
]

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "CUSTOM_URL",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode( $postfields ),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "authorization: Basic UN:PW",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
    ],
));
```

Comment: If you use `http_build_query` your content type should be `plain/text`

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks. coed fixed.